# Overriding BeanPropertyRowMapper to Support JodaTime DateTime

Tags: java, spring, jodatime, spring-jdbc

My Domain object has couple of Joda-Time `DateTime` fields. When I'm reading database values using SimpleJdbcTemplate:

> Patient patient = jdbc.queryForObject(sql, new
>   BeanPropertyRowMapper(Patient.class), patientId);

It just fails and surprisingly, no errors were logged. I guess it's because of the `timestamp` parsing to `DateTime` is not working with Jdbc.

If it's possible to inherit and override `BeanPropertyRowMapper` and instruct to convert all `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date` to `DateTime`, it would be great and could save a lot of extra code.

Any advice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct thing to do is to subclass `BeanPropertyRowMapper`, override `initBeanWrapper(BeanWrapper)` and register a custom Property Editor:

```
public class JodaDateTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(final String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(new DateTime(text)); // date time in ISO8601 format
                                      // (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ)
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(final Object value) {
        super.setValue(value == null || value instanceof DateTime ? value
                                        : new DateTime(value));
    }
    @Override
    public DateTime getValue() {
        return (DateTime) super.getValue();
    }
    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        return getValue().toString(); // date time in ISO8601 format
                                      // (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ)
    }
}
public class JodaTimeSavvyBeanPropertyRowMapper<T>
                  extends BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> {
    @Override
    protected void initBeanWrapper(BeanWrapper bw) {
        bw.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, new JodaDateTimeEditor());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, It's not really working for me. The execution stops the moment a DateTime mapping happens, however no errors logged: `DEBUG:com.keype.hawk.system.jdbc.support.HawkBeanPropertyRowMapper[mapRow]:Mapping column 'date_added' to property 'dateAdded' of type class org.joda.time.DateTime`

Comment: Finally managed to the problem area. setValue() is getting called with a TimeStamp object as parameter, but it's actually a JodaTime Per my logger: `Un supported object 2011-10-12 00:00:00.0. Object type: java.sql.Timestamp. Expected DateTime`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the working example! I have only one remark related to the naming of the class JodaTimeSavvyBeanPropertyRowMapper. It should not be named JodaTimeSavvyBeanPropertyRowMapper because we can register several  PropertyEditorSupport and not only Joda PropertyEditorSupport. In my code I named the class CustomBeanPropertyRowMapper. It is dedicated to all the Spring Batch reports that are generated and the name is rather generic.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `BeanPropertyRowMapper` implementation, the way it sets the fields is:

```
Object value = getColumnValue( rs, index, pd );

if (logger.isDebugEnabled() && rowNumber == 0) {
    logger.debug("Mapping column '" + column + "' to property '" +
    pd.getName() + "' of type " + pd.getPropertyType());
}
try {
    bw.setPropertyValue(pd.getName(), value);
}
```

where `getColumnValue(rs, index, pd);` delegates to [JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.html#getResultSetValue%28java.sql.ResultSet,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29)

That `pd` field in `getColumnValue` is the actual "**p** roperty **d** escriptor", that is used ( `pd.getPropertyType()` ) in `JdbcUtils` as a *type* of the field to map to.

If you look at `JdbcUtils` code for `getResultSetValue` method, you'll see that it simply goes from one `if` statement to another, to match `pd.getPropertyType()` to all standard types. When it does not find one, since `DateTime` is not a "standard" type, it relies on a `rs.getObject()`:

```
} else {
// Some unknown type desired -> rely on getObject.
```

Then if this object is a SQL Date it converts it to a `Timestamp`, and returns to be set to a `DateTime` field of your domain => where it fails.

Hence, there does not seem to be a straight forward way to inject a `Date`/`Timestamp` to `DateTime` converter into a `BeanPropertyRowMapper`. So it would be cleaner (and more performant) to implement your own RowMapper.

In case you'd like to see the mapping error in a console, set your logging level for `org.springframework.jdbc` to "debug" or better yet "trace" to see exactly what happens.

One thing you can try, which I have not tested, is to extend a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` and override a property of `DateTime` type in:

```
/**
 * Initialize the given BeanWrapper to be used for row mapping.
 * To be called for each row.
 * <p>The default implementation is empty. Can be overridden in subclasses.
 * @param bw the BeanWrapper to initialize
 */
 protected void initBeanWrapper(BeanWrapper bw) {}
```

Comment: Thanks tolitius. That's what I did. I couldn't figure out way either. A custom row matter it is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Sean Patrick Floyd is perfect until you do not have many many custom types.

Here it a generalized, configurable based on usage extension:

```
public class CustomFieldTypeSupportBeanPropertyRowMapper<T> extends BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> {
  private Map<Class<?>, Handler> customTypeMappers = new HashMap<Class<?>, Handler>();

  public CustomFieldTypeSupportBeanPropertyRowMapper() {
    super();
  }

  public CustomFieldTypeSupportBeanPropertyRowMapper(Class<T> mappedClass, boolean checkFullyPopulated) {
    super(mappedClass, checkFullyPopulated);
  }

  public CustomFieldTypeSupportBeanPropertyRowMapper(Class<T> mappedClass) {
    super(mappedClass);
  }

  public CustomFieldTypeSupportBeanPropertyRowMapper(Class<T> mappedClass, Map<Class<?>, Handler> customTypeMappers) {
    super(mappedClass);
    this.customTypeMappers = customTypeMappers;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getColumnValue(ResultSet rs, int index, PropertyDescriptor pd) throws SQLException {
    final Class<?> current = pd.getPropertyType();
    if (customTypeMappers.containsKey(current)) {
      return customTypeMappers.get(current).f(rs, index, pd);
    }
    return super.getColumnValue(rs, index, pd);
  }

  public void addTypeHandler(Class<?> class1, Handler handler2) {
    customTypeMappers.put(class1, handler2);
  }

  public static interface Handler {
    public Object f(ResultSet rs, int index, PropertyDescriptor pd) throws SQLException;
  }
}
```