# TimeZone isn't showing

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, kotlin, postman

I'm using IntelliJ (Kotlin and Java language), I'm trying to get a report of time by using query from my database and send that to the browser (I'm using Postman to see the result).

When I debug my code and go through the result from the query the timezone is ok like the way I want it, its even show -7 (the difference time between me and the UTC) but when it comes to the browser (Postman) it's showing `UTC` time and `+0000`, for example:

```
"date": "2017-10-12T15:00:33.000+0000"
```

instead of

```
"date": "2017-10-12T15:00:33.000+0007".
```

I tried many options and waste around 6 hours to find the solution but nothing work.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres stores a [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), discarding the passed zone after using it to make the adjustment into UTC. Note that this is Postgres-specific behavior – databases vary widely in their date-time handling, and the SQL spec barely touches on the subject.

As commented by Marlowe, if you need to remember the time zone captured from data-entry, you will need to store that in another column. Capture a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

➠ Here's the rub: A Postgres session in an interactive tool such as pgAdmin **dynamically applies a default time zone** after fetching the UTC value. While well-intentioned, this is an anti-feature in my opinion as it obscures the true nature of the stored data.

Fetch the value in UTC using the modern java.time classes.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Adjust to your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate a string for the web browser using the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Note the automatic localization features there.

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but because I'm using Kotlin I can't use your solution, i tried something similar before but no success

Comment: @TalShani that shouldn't matter. Kotlin is entirely capable of Java interop. In fact, if you copy-paste Java code into IntelliJ, it will offer to convert it to Kotlin.

Comment: @1blustone yeah i know but still doesn't work from any reason the data is right after i fix the time zone but on the second it supposed to go to the browser it change again

Comment: That's definitely not due to Kotlin.

Comment: If you need the db to remember the time zone you'll have to store it separately from the timestamp. Then you can apply it or do with with it as needed. Note that how timestamps with timezone are stored is, sadly, a SQL standard thing.

Comment: @TalShani Kotlin is fully interoperable with Java classes. So I do not understand your comment about not being able to use the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm sorry i didnt put attention, instead the ... (3 dots inside the getObject)  what should it be?

Comment: @TalShani Read the [`ResultSet` class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: @BasilBourque it require a String/Int type, but mine is TimeStamp. i wrapped the result from the query with an Object i created by BeanPropertyRowMapper...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** so i found the solution to my problem here:
[Overriding BeanPropertyRowMapper to Support JodaTime DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730529/overriding-beanpropertyrowmapper-to-support-jodatime-datetime)

in shortly, timestamp type doesn't work well with timezone so i changed it to DateTime in Joda and wrapped the result of the query by costumed Bean (from the link i posted)